# newcommand/mathsurround if there are more then 2 simple text spaces

Tags: math-mode, spacing

I want to use `\mathsurround` with more space then `0pt`, but with the condition, that there are more then 2 simple text spaces between 2 math mode environments.

The reason is, when I have an enumeration `$a$, $b$, $c$` separated with simple `,` that there is no extra space for ever numeration in between. So I want to have space in the text before and after every math mode, but where such enumerations as `$a$, $b$, $c$` are summarized (before `$a$` and after `$c$` there should be a space given by `\mathsurround`). Is this possible?

Comment: I suggest you to type simply `text $a,b,c$ text`.

Comment: Please share the Minimum Working Example (MWE) to show what has been done so far.